# How to Prove: $|Z_1 + Z_2| \leq |Z_1| + |Z_2|$

Tags: calculus

How to Prove: $$|Z_1 + Z_2| \leq |Z_1| + |Z_2|$$ $ Z_1,Z_2 \in \mathbb{C}$

Comment: If one is negative then it is smaller.

Comment: Geometrically , the length of one side of a triangle is less than the sum of the lengths of the two other sides .

Answer (score 3):

We use the identities $z\overline z=|z|^2,z+\overline z=2Re(z)$ and $|\overline z|=|z|$. We know $x\le \sqrt{x^2+y^2}$ for all $x,y\in \Bbb R$, therefore $Re(z)\le |z|$ for all $z\in \Bbb C$. From this we see $$\begin{align}Re(z_1\overline z_2)&\le&|z_1||\overline z_2|=|z_1||z_2|\\2Re(z_1\overline z_2)&\le&2|z_1||z_2|\\z_1\overline z_1+z_1\overline z_2+z_2\overline z_1+z_2\overline z_2&\le&z_1\overline z_1+2|z_1||z_2|+z_2\overline z_2\\(z_1+z_2)(\overline z_1+\overline z_2)&\le&|z_1|^2+2|z_1||z_2|+|z_2|^2\\|z_1+z_2|^2&\le&(|z_1|+|z_2|)^2\end{align}$$

Answer (score 2):

You want to prove that for any pair of points $(x_1,x_2),(y_1,y_2)$ we have $$\sqrt{(x_1+y_1)^2+(x_2+y_2)^2}\leq \sqrt{x_1^2+x_2^2}+\sqrt{y_1^2+y_2^2}$$

**Hint** After unwraping by squaring, use Cauchy Schwarz's inequality, namely $$|x_1y_1+x_2y_2|\leq \sqrt{x_1^2+x_2^2}\sqrt{y_1^2+y_2^2}$$

If you're familiar with the usual Euclidean norm $$\lVert x\rVert =\left(\sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2\right)^{1/2}$$ and the usual inner product $$\langle x,y\rangle =\sum_{i=1}^n x_iy_i$$ then you ought to use Cauchy Schwarz, that says $$\lvert \langle x,y\rangle \rvert\leq \lVert x\rVert\cdot \lVert y\rVert $$ Then $$\begin{align}\lVert x+y\rVert^2&=\lVert x\rVert^2+2\langle x,y\rangle +\lVert y\rVert^2\\& \leqslant \lVert x\rVert^2+2 \lVert x\rVert\cdot \lVert y\rVert +\lVert y\rVert^2\\&=(\lVert x\rVert+\lVert y\rVert)^2\end{align}$$

This is a special case of [Minkowski's inequality.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minkowski_inequality)

Answer (score 0):

https://www.math.ucdavis.edu/~forehand/67_summer2012_files/triangle%20inequality.pdf

The proof you want is in the link. It uses the fact that $|Z| = a^{2} + b^{2} = Z\overline{Z}$ where $ Z = a + bi$ and $\overline{Z} = a - bi$.